# Incorrect output from simplifying fraction

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple code, written to simplify fractions in python. Putting in certain numbers (Such as shown in the code) give huge, and possibly incorrect values. Below is the code.

```
from fractions import Fraction
print(Fraction(36/40))
```

And it outputs:

```
8106479329266893/9007199254740992
```

Why does it do this, and how can I fix this?

Comment: I'm going to guess it's just a floating point error? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you intended to use `Fraction(36, 40)`.
Notice the comma instead of the slash.
What happens is that you input a division result instead of the numerator and denominator.

There are quite a few ways to init the Fraction. Take a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html).

Comment: Does the docs article you have linked contain info over / vs , and other related things?

Comment: It's right at the beginning. Basically you can initialize the Fraction with two integer numbers (which I suggested), another fraction, a float number (which was unintentionally your case), a decimal number or a string. String will actually just get parsed to two integers.

Comment: @DanielLaCour The difference is in which constructor is called. Since a comma delimits function arguments, with a comma, you're supplying 2 arguments. With a slash, you're supplying 1 argument, which is the result of division.